# Angular 2 unit testing data passed from parent component to child component

Tags: unit-testing, angular, components

I have a question about the way I've seen (the very few) examples of testing of data passed down from a parent component into a child component. Currently, in the [Angular2 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#intercept-input-property-changes-with-ngonchanges-), they're testing to see if data has been passed down from a parent component to a child by *inspecting the dom values of the child component*. The issue that I have with this approach is that it forces the parent's spec to know the html structure of the child component. The parent component's job is just *to pass data into the child*. An example...

I have a Story Component as follows:

```
'use strict';

import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {StoryService} from '../../services/story.service';
import {StoryModel} from '../../models/story-model';
import {AlbumCover} from './album-cover/album-cover';
import {Author} from "./author/author";
import {StoryDuration} from "./story-duration/story-duration";

@Component({
    selector: 'story',
    templateUrl: 'build/components/story/story.html',
    providers: [StoryService],
    directives: [AlbumCover, Author, StoryDuration]
})

export class Story implements OnInit {
    @Input('id') id:number;
    public story:StoryModel;

    constructor(private storyService:StoryService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getStory();
    }

    private getStory() {
        this.storyService.getStory(this.id).subscribe(story => this.story = story);
    }
}
```

Notice how it has an `AlbumCover` Component dependency in the `directives` array in the `@Component` decorator.

Here is my Story template:

```
<div *ngIf="story">
    <album-cover [image]="story.albumCover" [title]="story.title"></album-cover>
    <div class="author-duration-container">
        <author [avatar]="story.author.avatar" [name]="story.author.name"></author>
        <story-duration [word-count]="story.wordCount"></story-duration>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the `<album-cover [image]="story.albumCover" [title]="story.title"></album-cover>` line where I'm binding the `story.albumCover` from the `Story` controller to the `image` property of the `AlbumCover`. This is all working perfectly. Now for the test:

```
import {provide} from '@angular/core';
import {beforeEach, beforeEachProviders, describe, expect, injectAsync, it, setBaseTestProviders, resetBaseTestProviders} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import {BROWSER_APP_DYNAMIC_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import {TEST_BROWSER_STATIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS, ADDITIONAL_TEST_BROWSER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/platform-browser/testing';
import {ComponentFixture, TestComponentBuilder} from '@angular/compiler/testing';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

// TODO: this pattern of importing 'of' can probably go away once rxjs is fixed
// https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1713
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

resetBaseTestProviders();
setBaseTestProviders(
    TEST_BROWSER_STATIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
    [BROWSER_APP_DYNAMIC_PROVIDERS, ADDITIONAL_TEST_BROWSER_PROVIDERS]
);

import {Story} from './story';
import {StoryModel} from '../../models/story-model';
import {StoryService} from '../../services/story.service';

var mockStory = {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Benefit',
    albumCover: 'images/placeholders/story-4.jpg',
    author: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Brett Beach',
        avatar: 'images/placeholders/author-1.jpg'
    },
    wordCount: 4340,
    content: '<p>This is going to be a great book! I <strong>swear!</strong></p>'
};

class MockStoryService {
    public getStory(id):Observable<StoryModel> {
        return Observable.of(mockStory);
    }
}

describe('Story', () => {
    var storyFixture,
        story,
        storyEl;

    beforeEachProviders(() => [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS
    ]);

    beforeEach(injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb:TestComponentBuilder) => {
        return tcb
            .overrideProviders(Story, [
                provide(StoryService, {
                    useClass: MockStoryService
                })
            ])
            .createAsync(Story)
            .then((componentFixture:ComponentFixture<Story>) => {
                storyFixture = componentFixture;
                story = componentFixture.componentInstance;
                storyEl = componentFixture.nativeElement;
                componentFixture.detectChanges();
            });
    }));

    describe(`ngOnInit`, () => {
        describe(`storyService.getStory`, () => {
            it(`should be called, and on success, set this.story`, () => {
                spyOn(story.storyService, 'getStory').and.callThrough();
                story.ngOnInit();
                expect(story.storyService.getStory).toHaveBeenCalled();
                expect(story.story.title).toBe('Benefit');
            });
        });
    });

    it('should not show the story component if story does not exist', () => {
        story.story = null;
        storyFixture.detectChanges();
        expect(storyEl.children.length).toBe(0);
    });

    it('should show the story component if story exists', () => {
        story.story = mockStory;
        storyFixture.detectChanges();
        expect(storyEl.children.length).not.toBe(0);
    });

    describe('story components', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            story.story = mockStory;
            storyFixture.detectChanges();
        });

        describe('album cover', () => {
            var element,
                img;

            beforeEach(() => {
                element = storyEl.querySelector('album-cover');
                img = element.querySelector('img');
            });

            it(`should be passed the story albumCover and title to the album cover component`, () => {
                expect(img.attributes.src.value).toBe(mockStory.albumCover);
                expect(img.attributes.alt.value).toBe(mockStory.title);
            });
        });

        describe('author', () => {
            var element,
                img,
                nameEl;

            beforeEach(() => {
                element = storyEl.querySelector('author');
                img = element.querySelector('img');
                nameEl = element.querySelector('.name');
            });

            it(`should be passed the author name and avatar`, () => {
                expect(img.attributes.src.value).toBe(story.story.author.avatar);
                expect(img.attributes.alt.value).toBe(story.story.author.name);
                expect(nameEl.innerText).toBe(story.story.author.name);
            });
        });

        describe('story duration', () => {
            var element;

            beforeEach(() => {
                element = storyEl.querySelector('.story-duration');
            });

            it(`should be passed the word count to generate the total read time`, () => {
                story.story.wordCount = 234234;
                storyFixture.detectChanges();
                expect(element.innerText).toBe(`852 min read`);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Look at my `describe('album cover'...`. The way I'm passing this expectation is that I'm finding the `<album-cover>` element, then finding the `<img>` tag inside of it, then checking the `<img>`'s DOM attributes. To me, this expection should be inside of the `album-cover.spec.ts` - NOT the `story.spec.ts`.

**My question is**: is there a way to test if a parent component passed data into a child component without relying on reading dom values?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `overrideTemplate` to pass a view just for the test.

```
   return tcb
        .overrideTemplate(AlbumCover, '<div>{{valueFromParent}}</div>')
        .overrideProviders(Story, [
```

Comment: Gunter, this is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Just updated my tests and it worked perfectly. Thank you!!!!