# Inspect the value of an attribute binding in a parent component's test

Tags: angular

I'm writing a test spec for a parent component containing a child component named `<album-art>`. How can I test that the `config` attribute has been assigned the `myConfigX` object like so:

```
<album-art [config]="myConfigX"></album-art>
```

The test should fail if:

```
<album-art [config]="myConfigY"></album-art>
```

I'm hoping to test the actual value of the binding without having to instantiate/mock the child component to ask it what it has received. More of a case of directly asking the parent component “what are you passing to this element’s attribute?".

Ideally, I'm looking for something like the example below but instead of returning `[Object object]` it'd return the `myConfigX` object instance:

```
expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('album-art').getAttribute('ng-reflect-config'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest I've been able to get is to create a super lightweight mock of the child component, select its `DebugElement` and test against its `componentInstance` like so:

Mock child component (add this to the testing module's declarations):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'album-art',
    template: '',
})
class MockAlbumArtComponent {
    @Input()
    config: AlbumArtConfig;
}
```

Parent component template:

```
...
<album-art [config]="myConfigX"></album-art>
...
```

Assertion:

```
expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('album-art')).componentInstance.config).toBe(instance.myConfigX, 'correct config object passed');
```

This is better than testing the interpolated values in a mock template [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37982738/619602) as in this example you can check the equality of actual object references.

It's a shame you can't access something like `fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('album-art')).inputs.config` though, in which case you wouldn't need the mock component!

Comment: where the "instance" is come from ? I am asking this because it  gives me an error when I have tried your example . Is something I need to import ?